# How could Symfony2 forms be used to validate data loaded from a file?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

From the [Symfony2 manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html), here is the way a form is validated:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();    
    $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), new Registration());    
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $registration = $form->getData();    
        $em->persist($registration->getUser());
        $em->flush();    
        return $this->redirect(...);
    }    
    return $this->render(
        'AcmeAccountBundle:Account:register.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

The bottom line is we have an entity `Registration` and a corresponding form `RegistrationType`. When we want to validate the data in the `$request` we use `$form->handleRequest($request);`

I wanna use the same approach, but when my entities are loaded from a file not posted via a form.

For example I have a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file that has a list of 100 users that I want to create accounts for, but the data needs to be validated the same way the form was validated and an array of errors can be extracted from the form class.

Is there a way to do this automatically using Symfony2 in a similar way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your answer will be here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

Comment: Exactly! you need to use the validator directly.

Comment: @vascowhite well as a last resort I could actually use the validators directly as you mentioned. I was just hoping to see a way to reuse the form class to validate data from files seeing that much of the work has already been done there :) Maybe I'll try to override the `handleRequest()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in a recent project we did that. But we read the entire file CSV and created some arrays wich hold the values. Then we made the objects with all the values from the file and each object was validated with the Symfony Validator. If you wanted to do it automaticly it's not possible, you have to do it by yourself.